# Get last element from wpdb as a string

Tags: wpdb

I need some help in getting single string from wpdb instead od array. The below code should return child post number. It will always return array with single element.

```
    global $wpdb;
$store = wp_get_current_user();
$store_id = $store->ID;
 $par_order = $reservation->transaction_id;
 $sql = "SELECT ID FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "posts
         WHERE post_type = 'shop_order'
         AND post_parent = " . $par_order
        . " AND post_author = " . $storer_id;
 $sub_orders = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Comment: Try `get_var` instead of `get_results` https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/

Comment: @czerspalace Unfortunetely it hasn't helped.

Comment: Is it still returning an array? Can you show your updated code with `get_var`?

Comment: @czerspalace Shame on me but I just replaced get_results with get_var, and honestly I have no idea what should I do with that. Could you give me a hand? I literally spent on it the whole day trying to make it work :P

Comment: When you replaced it, what did you see in $sub_orders?

Comment: @czerspalace $suborders doesn't return anything after I changed it to: ` `$sub_orders = $wpdb->get_var($sql); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out:

```
global $wpdb;
 $par_order = $reservation->transaction_id;
$store = wp_get_current_user();
$store_id = $store->ID;
    $sql = "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_order' AND post_parent = $par_order AND post_author = $store_id";
$sub_orders = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql,$seller_id));
```

thank you @czerspalace for the clue